# Proving Continuity of Piecewise Function

Tags: real-analysis, limits

> Let $f(x) = \cases{\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}\;\; x \ne 1 \\ a \;\;\;\;\;\;\; x = 1}$
>   
>   Prove that $f$ is continuous if and only if $a = 2$.

I'm not quite sure how to work the epsilon and delta jargon to prove this both ways! Could someone give me a hint?

Answer (score 1):

If you want $f$ to be continuous, you only need to have $\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=f(1)$ (your $f$ is continuous in all other points because it is a polynomial: $\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=x+1$).

$\lim_{x\to 1}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 1}(x+1)=1+1=2$,

so $a=2$ is the only case.

Answer (score 0):

Notice:
$$L=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{x^2-1}{x-1}=\lim_{x\to1}\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}=(x+1)\bigg|_{x=1}=2.$$

For $f$ to be continuous, the limit $L$ must be equal to $f(1)$:
$$f(1)=a=L=2,$$

which completes the proof.